# Android: static status bar notification

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

How to create a static status bar notification? Like in skype app or others...
It must be visible while app is running, even if it runs in background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a notification and include `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` in the set of flags.  Note that when your application is finished, you should cancel the notification.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: The point of my question is how to make notification always wisible.